# Docker failed to load listeners, cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using [this guide](https://dev.to/_nicolas_louis_/how-to-run-docker-on-windows-without-docker-desktop-hik) to try and run up Docker using WSL2. I've got everything starting however there is an issue when I actually try to run up Docker. Once I run the command `` sudo dockerd -H `ifconfig eth0 | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -f2 -d: ``

```
WARN[2022-02-01T11:07:40.033323500-06:00] Binding to IP address without --tlsverify is insecure and gives root access on this machine to everyone who has access to your network.  host="tcp://169.254.77.26:2375"
WARN[2022-02-01T11:07:40.033991800-06:00] Binding to an IP address, even on localhost, can also give access to scripts run in a browser. Be safe out there!  host="tcp://169.254.77.26:2375"
WARN[2022-02-01T11:07:41.036303800-06:00] Binding to an IP address without --tlsverify is deprecated. Startup is intentionally being slowed down to show this message  host="tcp://169.254.77.26:2375"
WARN[2022-02-01T11:07:41.043536700-06:00] Please consider generating tls certificates with client validation to prevent exposing unauthenticated root access to your network  host="tcp://169.254.77.26:2375"
WARN[2022-02-01T11:07:41.044564400-06:00] You can override this by explicitly specifying '--tls=false' or '--tlsverify=false'  host="tcp://169.254.77.26:2375"
WARN[2022-02-01T11:07:41.045654100-06:00] Support for listening on TCP without authentication or explicit intent to run without authentication will be removed in the next release  host="tcp://169.254.77.26:2375"
failed to load listeners: listen tcp 169.254.77.26:2375: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

I'm not too familiar with Docker so not sure what I can adjust to make it launch properly. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As the error messages indicate, that `dockerd -H` option is extremely dangerous (it opens up a very easy remote root exploit).  The default Ubuntu Docker setup would be to listen on a Unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock`; is that a setup that works in WSL2?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing exactly the same.

What worked for me was this comment https://dev.to/nelsonpena/comment/1jmkb . But it was not too explicit

1. I opened windows PowerShell and used the command
   `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2`
   if you have another distro of linux it would be
   `wsl --set-version <distroname> 2`
2. I closed wsl and opened it again. and executed the command
   `` echo `ifconfig eth0 | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{ print $2;exit }' | cut -f2 -d:` ``
   and got API listen on [the IP]